# pandas pivot multi-indexed columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, multi-index

I want to pivot a multi-indexed datafame but fail with:

```
 Shape of passed values is (3, 4), indices imply (3, 2)
```

the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': [1,2,3], 'bar':[4,5,6], 'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'], 'cat':['a', 'b', 'b']
})
df = df.groupby(['dt', 'cat']).describe().loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['count', '50%']]].reset_index()
columns_of_interest = sorted(df.drop(['dt', 'cat'], axis=1, level=0).columns.get_level_values(0).unique())
df.pivot(index='dt', columns='cat', values=columns_of_interest)
```

How can it be fixed?

### edit

Expected result:

from:

```
dt  cat     foo     bar
            count   50%     count   50%
0   2020-01-01  a   1.0     1.0     1.0     4.0
1   2020-01-01  b   1.0     2.0     1.0     5.0
2   2020-01-02  b   1.0     3.0     1.0     6.0
```

to:

```
value       foo         bar

cat     a       b       a       b
dt

0
1
2
```

### edit 2

basically I want to calculate:

```
v = 'count'
df['foo'][v].reset_index().pivot(index='dt', columns='cat', values = v)
```

for each column `[foo, bar]` and each aggregation `[count, 50%]` and get a single combined result back.

I.e.:

```
for c in columns_of_interest:
    print(c)    
    for piv in piv_values:
        print(piv)
        r = df[c][piv].reset_index().pivot(index='dt', columns='cat', values = piv)
        display(r)
```

1) I am just not sure how to recombine the results yet and 2) how to find a neat solution.

#### workaround

A rather neat workaround is to flatten the level:

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
columns_of_interest = df.columns
df.reset_index().pivot(index='dt', columns='cat', values=columns_of_interest)
```

Comment: There are many ways to "fix" this.  We have to know what you were expecting.

Comment: In a naive way I would say a triple index .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `unstack` after the `groupby` (no reset_index):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': [1,2,3], 'bar':[4,5,6], 
    'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'], 'cat':['a', 'b', 'b']
})
df_ = df.groupby(['dt', 'cat']).describe()\
        .loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['count', '50%']]]\
        .unstack() # unstack instead of reset_index

print (df_)
             foo                  bar               
           count       50%      count       50%     
cat            a    b    a    b     a    b    a    b
dt                                                  
2020-01-01   1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0   1.0  1.0  4.0  5.0
2020-01-02   NaN  1.0  NaN  3.0   NaN  1.0  NaN  6.0
```